# PHP месяц текстом по-русски перевести в число?

Tags: php, дата

Есть следующий нерабочий код:
$os = '27 августа 2020 19:12';
return DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y H:i', $os)->format('d-m-Y G:i:s');

Проблема вероятно  в формате в букве "F" отвечающей за месяц, т.к. если без неё, то всё работает и вроде даже правильно:
$os = '27 2020 19:12';
return DateTime::createFromFormat('d Y H:i', $os)->format('d-m-Y G:i:s');

Непонятно как определяется август, если в переменной его нет?

И как всё таки правильно вывести код с указанием месяца текстом?

Comment: Попробуйте изменить локаль. на `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.cp1251');` или `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');` перед вызовом DateTime..

Comment: Если здесь: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_php_interpreter использую такой код:
$os = '27 августа 2020 19:12';
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d F Y H:i', $os)->format('d-m-Y G:i:s');

Получаю ошибку: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in /home/main.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/main.php on line 13

Comment: Замену месяца текстом на цифру удалось реализовать кодом: $months = array("января" => "01", "февраля" => "02", 
"марта" => "03", "апреля" => "04", "мая" => "05", "июня" => "06", 
"июля" => "07", "августа" => "08", "сентября" => "09",
"октября" => "10", "ноября" => "11", "декабря" => "12");
$os = strtr($os, $months); получается дата вида: 27 08 2020 19:12, но превратить её в нужный формат не получается, использую: $os = DateTime::createFromFormat('d m Y H:i', $os)->format('d-m-Y G:i:s'); как преобразовать в нужный формат?